# Is there a 2-categorical, equivariant version of Quillen's Theorem A?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, group-actions, equivariant-homotopy

Quillen's **Theorem A** says that a functor $F:C \to D$ (between 1-categories) induces a homotopy equivalence of classifying spaces $BC \simeq BD$ if for every object $d$ in $D$ the fiber category $F/d$ has a contractible classifying space.

> Quick reminder: the objects of $F/d$ are pairs $(c,\gamma)$ consisting of an object $c$ in $C$ and a morphism $\gamma:Fc \to d$ in $D$; and morphisms $(c,\gamma) \to (c',\gamma')$ in $F/d$ are given by all $f:c \to c'$ in $C$ satisfying $\gamma = \gamma' \circ Ff$ in $D$.

Here are two natural extensions of this result:

1. If a group $\Gamma$ acts on $C$ and $D$ with $F$ an $\Gamma$-equivariant functor, then $F$ induces a $\Gamma$-equivariant homotopy equivalence between $C$ and $D$ provided its fibers are $\Gamma$-equivariantly contractible. I must confess that the only published version that I am aware of restricts to the case where $C$ and $D$ are $\Gamma$-posets, due to Thevanaz and Webb (pdf [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82470779.pdf))
2. If we're working with a (lax/oplax) 2-functor between $2$ categories, then Quillen's Theorem A holds provided we define the lax fiber 2-categories $F/d$ correctly; I learned this from Bullejos and Cegarra's [paper](http://www.ugr.es/%7Ebullejos/geometryampl.pdf) (pdf, see Thm 2)

---

My question is, **is the union of 1 and 2 published somewhere**? Which is to say, if I have a (lax/oplax) functor $F:C \to D$ between $2$-categories which is equivariant with respect to the action of some group $\Gamma$, and if its fiber 2-categories are $\Gamma$-equivariantly contractible, can I automatically claim that $F$ induces a $\Gamma$-equivariant homotopy equivalence between classifying spaces?

What I'm hoping to avoid is the scenario where the result is decipherable "*only from the corresponding result for sheaves on $(\infty,1)$-topoi*" or something similar. For reasons both psychological and mathematical, I'd like to restrict the categorical depth to $\leq 2$ if at all possible.

Comment: You say you want to avoid $\infty$-categories, but as nobody has provided such an answer, perhaps it's worth mentioning that Quillen's Theorem A has a natural strengthening $\infty$-categorically: an $\infty$-functor satisfies the the hypotheses of Quillen's Theorem A if and only if it is _cofinal_. See HTT 4.1.3. One place the equivariant (over a finite group) version of this is carried out is (in in the more general setting of parametrized $\infty$-category theory) in Thm 6.7 of Jay Shah's thesis [Parametrized Higher Category Theory](http://jshah3.esc.nd.edu/thesis.pdf).

Comment: For a more point-set-style approach to equivariant cofinality, see Theorem 2.25 of Dotto and Moi's [Homotopy theory of $G$-diagrams and equivariant excision](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1510841110).

Comment: Did you ever find a reference for the 1-categorical version?  I need it for a paper and I'm not sure my target audience would easily be able to see it follows from Tim's references which prove more general.things.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg sorry, no. I managed to bypass the need for it after several failed attempts at googling

Comment: @ViditNanda thanks